# Unable to Configure Azure Function with Crom Expression from Settings

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've read about how you can use a cron expression from `local.settings.json` (and presumably from settings on the portal) by using a %% notation in the TimerTrigger parameter.

I'm not having much luck. I added the following to my `local.settings.json`:

```
  "Payments": {
    "StripePaymentThirdRetry": {
      "Cron": "0 */2 * * * *"
    }
  }
```

And then added this to my TimerTrigger parameter:

```
public async Task RunThird([TimerTrigger("%Payments:StripePaymentThirdRetry:Cron%")] TimerInfo myTimer, MsLogging.ILogger log)
```

The error I get is:

> > [2022-07-19T05:59:55.917Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'StripePaymentThirdRetry'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: '%Payments:StripePaymentThirdRetry:Cron%' does not resolve to a value.
> > [2022-07-19T05:59:55.948Z] Error indexing method 'StripePaymentThirdRetry'
> > [2022-07-19T05:59:55.949Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'StripePaymentThirdRetry'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: '%Payments:StripePaymentThirdRetry:Cron%' does not resolve to a value.
> > [2022-07-19T05:59:55.949Z] Function 'StripePaymentThirdRetry' failed indexing and will be disabled.
> > [2022-07-19T05:59:55.982Z] The 'StripePaymentThirdRetry' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'StripePaymentThirdRetry'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: '%Payments:StripePaymentThirdRetry:Cron%' does not resolve to a value.
> > [2022-07-19T05:59:55.982Z] The 'StripePaymentThirdRetry' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'StripePaymentThirdRetry'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: '%Payments:StripePaymentThirdRetry:Cron%' does not resolve to a value.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong. I've seen some suggestion that a `function.json` file is required, but the doco says that is only for non-compiled languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`local.settings.json` doesn't really work like a normal `appsettings.json`. Settings needs to be inside the `Values` property and it doesn't really like `Section`. If you use `__` it will be able to resolve to the desired setting:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "Payments__StripePaymentThirdRetry__Cron": "0 */2 * * * *"
  }
}
```

Comment: I did try Values. Will try this as soon as I get to work tomorrow. There's currently no Values key, so I'm wondering where it is pulling the other values from. Maybe the `host.json`.

Comment: That did not solve the issue. Something is still not correct.

Comment: what's the new error ? I did got it working on my side.

Comment: Same error. In addition, as an experiment, I tried to disable the function as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-local#local-settings-file) . That was ineffective as well.

Comment: OK. I found a way. The function is pulling its settings from a Settings thing on the portal (forgive my terms - I'm not a cloud guy). If I put a setting on the cloud, it works. I **thought** that a setting in local settings would override that for debugging. If it is meant to work that way, something in this project is awry.

Comment: you mean your local function ? settings should be in the local.settings.json file for debug then one deploy on the configuration tab (portal).

Comment: That is exactly how I want it to work. In Startup, the ConfigurationBuilder is calling .AddAzureAppConfiguration i.e. `new ConfigurationBuilder().AddAzureAppConfiguration(endpoint)` . So, I think the local settings json file is being ignored or overridden. The weird thing is, the cloud settings don't contain a value for AzureWebJobsStorage, so I'm not sure what it is using for storage when deployed.

Comment: Oh Azure App configuration. Yeah then the setting needs to be in Azure App Configuration.

Comment: for the AzureWebJobsStorage, check the configuration blade on your function app

Comment: Oh yeah, there it is! Thanks. Learnt a few things from you here. Really wish the local settings worked. Need to work on that. [This blog post](https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/why-wont-you-load-my-configuration-azure-functions) runs through a similar experience, but I don't really want to be deploying appsetting files, so his solution does not work for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

According to MS Doc of [Azure functions Timer Trigger Cron Schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#attributes), you have to define every attribute in values section like:

**local.settings.json**:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "Payments_StripePaymentThirdRetry_cron": "0 */2 * * * *"
      }
}
```

**Code**

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("%Payments_StripePaymentThirdRetry_cron%")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
```

**Result**:

[image]

and as per this **[local.settings.json azure functions official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-local#local-settings-file)**,

> Values must be strings and not JSON objects or arrays. Setting names can't include a double underline (`__`) and shouldn't include a colon (`:`). Double underline characters are reserved by the runtime, and the colon is reserved to support [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#working-with-options-and-settings).

Comment: Thanks. I did try Values, but not every value. Probably my mistake. Will try this as soon as I get to work tomorrow.

Comment: That has not worked. It is still throwing the same error.

Comment: As you didn't mention it is not working in local or portal, so I have shown the example in locally. for the portal app configuration, you're correct what you tried!